# javascript current time on digitalocean

Tags: javascript, digital-ocean

so i have this code on my web app that gives me the current date, but for some reason when i host it on digital ocean on a nyc server it gives me the next date for example the date today is 1/6/2020, but it logs out 1/7/2020

```
            var currentdate = new Date();

            //get current date
            var datetime = (currentdate.getMonth() + 1) + "/"
                + currentdate.getDate() + "/"
                + currentdate.getFullYear();

            console.log(datetime);
```

Comment: probably a timezone issue, i assume the nyc server has a considerable different timezone to yours. E.g. for me, it is already 1/7/2020

Comment: yeah but doesnt nyc stand for new york and the date in nyc is 1/6/2020

Comment: are you sure the server is not on UTC, like a good server should be?

Comment: no it is, it should be on the UTC timezone. I dont know whats wrong. it says that my servers region is nyc1

Comment: it is already 7/1/2020 in UTC.

Comment: If you can remote to the server then can try running 'date' command to output the date time for linux and windows in the console

Comment: Also a maybe stupid remark, but i so far assumed that this code is being run server side (node), and is not a website that you then run on your own PC.

Comment: thanks for helping but i figured it out i logged in remotely to the server and changed the time to my time zone this is the command to change the timezone if anyone out there runs through this problem: [  sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata ]

Answer (score 0):

this is the command to change your timezone on Ubuntu server if you can remotely login

```
     sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata
```